# Error when i do ''make'' in cado-nfs map

Tags: command-line, python, install-from-source, cmake

When I’m in terminal and in the map `cado-nfs`.
Then I do `make`.
It will run for a second or two and then I gives a stops and gives this error:

```
CMake Error at config/python.cmake:32 (message):
  Did not find a Python interpreter of one of the versions: 3.4;3.3;3.2.
  Please see README.Python
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:129 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jorrit/Desktop/cado-nfs-2.0/build/jorrit-VirtualBox/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/jorrit/Desktop/cado-nfs-2.0/build/jorrit-VirtualBox/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What to do?

Comment: `Did not find a Python interpreter of one of the versions: 3.4;3.3;3.2.`

Comment: What is in "Please see README.Python" ?

Comment: Did you try to use sudo apt-get install libgmp*-dev??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2.0 has many open bugs. I had success with version 2.1.1.

Comment: it's says then python3 is already installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded, bit stil gives a error

Comment: And with reinstall?

Comment: i tried that already stil gives the error

Comment: What says `which python`

Comment: wwhat do you mean?

Comment: Open a terminal and run `which python`

Comment: /usr/bin/python

Comment: Then check the both log files for more Infos `home/jorrit/Desktop/cado-nfs-2.0/build/jorrit-VirtualBox/CMakeFiles/"`

Comment: i dont know what i need to see in this log i see that the output was 0 everytime

Comment: Hmm, can you find `readme.python`?

Comment: yes i can find that in the map cad-nfs-2.0

Comment: Any interesting?

Comment: it says Python 3, version 3.2 or greater, is required for cadofactor.py. If you do
not wish to use cadofactor.py, for example because you want to use the old
cadofactor.pl Perl script or, for the brave, run all commands by hand, you
can disable the Python check in CMake by setting NO_PYTHON_CHECK to any
non-empty string in local.sh. See local.sh.example for a template

Comment: what happens if you type `python` in terminal

Comment: then i get into python 2.7.6 and i need to be python 3.2 or higher

Comment: Is there an executable `configure` or `configure.sh`

Comment: in the map python-3.4.3 there is a configure bit when i do ./configure and make it gives a weird error i do make then in the map python to install python                          # is not available in configure
sed -e "s,@EXENAME@,/usr/local/bin/python3.4m," < ./Misc/python-config.in >python-config.py
# Replace makefile compat. variable references with shell script compat. ones;  -> 
sed -e 's,\$(\([A-Za-z0-9_]*\)),\$\{\1\},g' < Misc/python-config.sh >python-config

Comment: "update-alternatives --config python" can you select python3?

Comment: it says "no alternatives for python''

Comment: Is it an option to remove python2

Comment: how can i do that then?

Comment: no, is not a good idea

Comment: what can i do than?

Comment: What are you trying to compile. Is there a project page? I might check it out tomorrow and try it yourself.

Comment: al my files are bitcrypt and i found this forum on the web so i want to try to decrypt it.http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/526536/bitcrypt-virus-help-me/

Comment: Ok, tomorrow. ☺

Comment: The Python problem I have here, too. But you should try version 2.1.1. This will compile without problems for me.

Comment: so i need to install python 2.1.1?! but it says i need a python 3.2 or higher

Comment: No, not python cado-nfs: https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/file/34110/cado-nfs-2.1.1.tar.gz

Comment: when i do now make it gives a error about gnu.mp how do i install that?

Comment: `gnu.mp` not `gmp.h`? `sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev`

Comment: yeah gnu.p mybad i need to enable MPI i think its gives a error --mpi is not enabled --configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Comment: I fixed it already i think its running now good!

Comment: That makes me happy. Give me an upvote :)